# Adobe Reader importing XML data using command line reference

Tags: pdf, fdf

Financial Gonverment in Poland prepared new VAT declarations, which are protected from changing. 
Restrictions summary is as follows: Printing, Commenting, Filling of form fields: Allowed; other restrictions are not allowed. 
I am able to export xml data, using Acrobat Reader, change it to have desired data and than import it and everything works fine. In ERP program I need to fill this document with data from the system. Normally we were doing this using FDF printing channel, but for this document it shows an error with bad user password. We were talking with people from government and only answer was that it is not possible to change document restrictions... We find out the way to create xml document, but we want it now to open from the command line (UNIX commands). But we only find the way to open pdf file with specified fdf file... But when I'm trying to open PDF document with specified fdf URL (url is linked to xml file... i don't know if it is proper... if not than how to create fdf file with desired xml?)

Is there any possible to open a pdf with specified xml url to load to that PDF?

Comment: is there any possibility to open pdf with imported data via xml file in command line?